# Can I use a capacitor to smooth out 5v from an Atrix Lapdock USB to Raspberry Pi via GPIO?

Tags: usb, gpio

I have created the Raspberry Pi Laptop project using an Atrix Lapdock and Raspberry Pi 3B. Can putting a cap on the 5v pin that I'm feeding power from the lapdock help smooth out any minor fluctuations in power draw due to variables such as clock speed changes? I'm a noob, so if I'm completely wrong, please help me understand.

Comment: How would the devices and the capacitor be connected, can you draw a diagram? Which capacitor would you be using? Why do you want to overclock stuff and give overvoltage to them, usually they just wear out and stop working faster? Capacitor also does not smooth out minor fluctuations in current, but voltage, and larger capacitor allows to smooth voltage under even larger current fluctuations. Maybe you mean to smooth out voltage fluctuations?

Comment: To effectively design a filter, you need to know what you are filtering out. A capacitor may help with some dips, but you need to know how big they are and duration. If you have a noisy supply you may need more complicated filtering like an RCL or RC filter, but again, you need to know specifics.